# matplotlib, step by step animation

Tags: matplotlib

It's a pretty basic question on matplotlib, but I cannot figure out how to do it :

I want to plot multiple figures and use the arrow in the plot window to move from one to another.

for the time being I just know how to create mutiple plots and plot them in different windows like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(1)
n= plt.bar([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])
plt.figure(2)
n= plt.bar([1,2,3,4],[-1,-2,-3,-4])
plt.show()
```

or having multiple figures on the same window using subplot.

How can I have mutliple plots on the same window and move from one to the next one with the arrows ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm very confused by "mutliple plots on the same window and move from one to the next one with the arrows"... Can you explain what you're wanting in another way?

Comment: @JoeKington I would like to have an animated bar chart I would animate using the arrows (next and forward) in the figure window.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To produce a plot which is updated as you press the left and right keys, you will need to handle keyboard events (docs: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html).

I have put together an example of updating a plot, using the pyplot interface, when you press the left and right arrows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = np.linspace(1, 100)
power = 0
plt.plot(data**power)


def on_keyboard(event):
    global power
    if event.key == 'right':
        power += 1
    elif event.key == 'left':
        power -= 1

    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(data**power)
    plt.draw()

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_keyboard)

plt.show()
```